# Actions on Google release date for Pixel, Allo and Android 6.0+ devices?

Tags: android, release, actions-on-google

I'm currently developing a home automation solution and I want to integrate Google Assistant on it.

I have already developed my conversational bot with API.ai and it's working great in the Google Home Web Simulator but in the future, I want that my bot can be run from any device with Google Assistant (Android 6.0+ devices if I'm not wrong).

I found this on Actions on Google website:

> Actions on Google let you build for the Google Assistant. Your integrations can help you engage users through Google Home today, **and in the future, through Pixel, Allo, and many other experiences where the Google Assistant will be available**.

So, when Actions on Google will be available for other platform that Google Home?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not ask a programming question - it asks for a non-developer software roadmap.

Comment: Indeed it's not a programming question but I really don't know where to ask the question and it seems that people that have an answer are here. If somebody just know where I can ask this, I'll close the question immediately ;)

Comment: While I suspect the official answer will be "Google does not comment on future product releases", the Actions community forum at https://plus.google.com/communities/105684267327487893574 is probably the best place to discuss it.

Comment: The comment is not clear. It could indicate that when Google Assistant is available on these mobile devices ... that Google Actions will be available on those devices. Google Assistant IS available on many devices. So is there something that a developer has to do to ENABLE their Actions on these mobile platform. Google Assistant on the mobile platform recognizes your Actions .... and responds with: Your <Invokation phrase> is not supported on this devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google annonced at the Google I/O'17 that Actions on Google is now available on Android 6.0+ devices in en-US language. 
Google Assistant will be available on other countries during summer 2017 (no precision about Actions on Google internationalization).